# get_or_insert, How to know it's created or retrieved?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use [get_or_insert](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert), But how do I know that it's just created or fetched from existing entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't. `get_or_insert` is just a convenience function, though, and one you can write and improve for yourself quite easily. Here's a simple replacement that returns a tuple, indicating if it was created or not:

```
@classmethod
def my_get_or_insert(cls, key_name, parent=None, **kwargs):
  def _tx():
    entity = cls.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=parent)
    if entity:
      return entity, False
    entity = cls(key_name=key_name, parent=parent, **kwargs)
    entity.put()
    return entity, True
  return db.run_in_transaction(_tx)
```

And here's how you'd use it:

```
entity, created = MyKind.my_get_or_insert('foo', bar=123)
if created:
  # Do whatever you do with a new entity here.
```

Just bear in mind that if you use it with the recipe above, anything you do based on whether the entity is new or not is not transactional - your code could fail after creating the entity but before doing that. If what you want to do has side-effects, you should probably do it inside the transaction.